# if something exist do something

Tags: templates, content-management-system, template-engine, movabletype

I have something like this:

```
<mt:Entries tags="@feature1" lastn="1">
<mt:EntryBody$>
</mt:Entries>
```

I would like to add an @test tag. If there is an entry that has an @test tag then show that entry. Otherwise show @feature1. Anyone know how I would go about that?

Comment: Could you please describe more precisly what you want to do. Are you going through a text file and you are looking for @test Tags? What do you mean by "then show that entry"?

Comment: sorry my code didn't save...`code`<mt:Entries tags="@feature1" lastn="1">
<mt:EntryBody$>
</mt:Entries>`code`. If I put that in my template it will display the last entry that has a @feature1 tag. I want to know if there is an @test tag anywhere in entries and if there is then display one way and if not display something else. How would I write it to check?

Answer (score 2):

Tested working in MT4.35:

```
<mt:entries tag="@test1" limit="0"><$mt:entriescount setvar="testFlag"$></mt:entries>
<mt:if name="testFlag">
    <mt:entries tags="@test1" limit="1">
    <$mt:entrytitle$>
    </mt:entries>
<mt:else>
    <mt:entries tags="@feature1" limit="1">
    <$mt:entrytitle$>
    </mt:entries>
</mt:if>
```

If the output format of the two cases is identical, there's a couple ways this could be compressed some, but I've left it verbose for clarity.